# Google Adsense ad not showing up in Jquery Mobile served by django

Tags: django, jquery-mobile, adsense

I'm trying to get a Google AdSense ad to display on my mobile website.  I am using Django to serve my web pages and I'm using JQuery Mobile to display and format the content.  I've followed [these blog instructions](http://therockncoder.blogspot.com/2012/08/jquery-mobile-and-adsense.html)  on a static html page and the ad shows up fine.  When I use the **exact same** code in my base template, the mobile ad does not show.  When I compare the HTML source code they look exactly the same and all the links work exactly the same.  Is there something Django injects into the header that would keep the ad from displaying?  The HTML source is as follows:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>Test AdSense</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css"/>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
        google_ad_client = "ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        /* LTC MobileHeader */
        google_ad_slot = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
        google_ad_width = 320;
        google_ad_height = 50;
    //-->
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="Div1" data-role="page" data-ajax="false">
        <header data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script>
            <h1>Index Page</h1>
        </header>
        <section data-role="content">
            <a href="page2.html" data-role="button" data-ajax="false">to Page 2</a>
        </section>
        <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"></footer>      
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it looks a little odd. why is the ad inside the <head> and the adsense .js inside the <body>? Should be the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to upload the code to my staging system system which runs on Ubuntu and the ads show up fine.  There is something going on with my development environment which runs on windows that is blocking the call to Google.